# Making QGIS display plugins that are installed on PC?

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-2.16

[image]How can I make QGIS 2.16 display plugins that are installed on my PC?

I'm getting what is shown in the picture below.

[image: qgis plugin]

Comment: From the message, It sounds you may have some plugins that need to be re-installed? Did you try uninstalling and re-installing the latest versions?

Comment: From the image, I get the sense that you haven't connected to the QGIS plugin repository since everything shown in your image are the plugins that are installed by default.

Comment: Click on the installed tab on the left.

Comment: All what you see is all what is installed on your PC. You're missing... all the non installed ones, in fact Something is wrong, Are you connected to internet from behind a proxy ?

Comment: could you include a screenshot of your settings (from the same dialog, but click on the settings tab first - the cog wheel icon)? There should be at least one entry in there, and it should have a green icon and say 'connected'

Comment: As @Zoltan said, you need to click the installed tab on the left. Also, there is a good chance that there is some kind of firewall blocking your access to the repository. I cannot access the repository though QGIS when I am at work. You have to manually download them from the [official plugin repository website](https://plugins.qgis.org/).

Comment: If you click on the `Settings tab`, do you see the Official Plugin Repository as `connected`? Currently, you see the samel plugins under `All` and `Installed`.